# java.sql.SQLExecption:parameter index out of range (1>number of prameters, which is 0) for update sql

Tags: java, mysql

i have problem with my project, and it still new for me with MYSQL, i want to get data from database and do some calculation and update the value on it,
its like making withdraw function like ATM machine. This my table look like.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTQF4.png) . You can see constructor parameter that carry value (String value and String ID). For Value="100"; and ID="5221311" you can see it on my table picture.

```
public ConformWithdraw() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.jdbc.mysql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:/atm", "root", "");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
  public ConformWithdraw(String value,String ID) {
    initComponents();
    this.value=value;
    this.ID=ID;
  }
------------------------------------------------------------ 



private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
try {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atm?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
    String validate = "SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE accountID LIKE '" + ID
                +  "'";
    PreparedStatement smtm = con.prepareStatement(validate);
    ResultSet resultSet = smtm.executeQuery();
    User user = null;

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            user = new User();
            user.setBalance(resultSet.getString("accountBalance"));
            double balance=Double.parseDouble(user.getBalance());
            double val=Double.parseDouble(value);
            total =(balance - val);
        }
        smtm.close();
        resultSet.close();
        program();


} catch (SQLException | HeadlessException | ClassCastException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);

}


 } 
-------------------------------------------------------------

 public void program(){

String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE customer_details "
            + "SET accountBalance = '"+String.valueOf(total)+"'"
            + "WHERE accountID = '"+ID+"'";
try{
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atm?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
        id=Integer.parseInt(ID);
            pstmt.setString(1, String.valueOf(total));

             pstmt.setInt(2, id);

        int rowAffected  = pstmt.executeUpdate();
    pstmt.close();
       new ShowWithdraw().setVisible(true);
       dispose();

}catch(SQLException | HeadlessException | ClassCastException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "slh sini");
}

}
```

Comment: I think you should research how to [set parameters on PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) before anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already setting the parameters on the query, so It tries to set the parameters and find no  parameters to find. Try this:

```
String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE customer_details "
        + "SET accountBalance = ?"
        + "WHERE accountID = ?";
```

Comment: sure @AriffNaj. Please consider vote up if it was helpful or/and mark as solution if it solved your issue :)